# Grab data from database and turn into variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

What is the fastest and easiest way to get a specific value from a mysql database table and echo it as a php variable?

For example:

I have a table like so:

```
label            value
------------------------
postpage         About
name             My Blog
```

I want to echo out the value column that has a label of postpage. In this case it would be the text "About". How would I do this with as little code as possible using php and mysql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started. Keep in mind it is a very simple example, and there are other visual/security changes you would need to make in a real application:

```
<?php
//Connect to your database....

$info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `your-table` WHERE `label` = 'postpage'"));
echo $info['value'];
?>
```

Comment: aren't label & value the COLUMNS? 'name' is data

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pass");
mysql_select_db("database");
$value = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT value FROM table WHERE label = 'postpage'"));
echo $value['postpage'];
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Your SQL query is wrong I believe, label & value are the COLUMNS in the table

Comment: There is a typo: `mysql_feth_assoc` => `mysql_fetch_assoc` and `SELECT postpage FROM` => `SELECT value FROM`

Comment: Sorry. I did it in hurry. I checked my whole code and it should be ok right now ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
//connect with database

$result = mysql_query("SELECT label, value FROM table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["label"] . ": ". $row["value"];
}
```

This will output all your labels & value

If you want only label postage just add the WHERE clause in the query:

```
SELECT label, value FROM table WHERE label = 'postage'
```